# I have the download URLs of my Firebase images, and I want to convert those to references to the images in the cloud. Is there a clean way to do so?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

The end objective is to delete those images, if that matters, and I have a `StorageReference` to my images folder in Firestore in the same scope.

Here is the code snippet:

```kotlin
    private val images = ArrayList<MyImage>()
    private val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
        .child("images")

    fun delete(position: Int): Boolean {
        val toDelete = images[position].url
        
        // And then what?

        return true
    }
```

The `MyImage` object simply contains the bitmap of the image, user-gen caption, and the download url.

How can I get a reference to the file and tell Firestore to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [storage.refFromUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#reffromurl) to turn the download URL into a reference.

In any cases, its easier to simply store a path to the file in storage along with the download URL to make this easier to work with.

Comment: I just tried using that. I ended up with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.` exception. The download links I have stored are `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A72` links if that matters.

Comment: That's not a download URL at all.  That's an Android content URI that refers to some local resource.

Comment: Ah! Okay, that explains why it didn't work. I figured out what I was doing wrong and it was somewhere else. I was getting the download link, but stored the local path in my model object. Thanks!

Comment: @DougStevenson Hey Doug. I think [FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getreferencefromurl) is more likely to be used, as the OP is asking this question for Kotlin and the resource you linked is for JavaScript.